Check my Math re: added accuracy vs added damage
I'm trying to answer for myself as a GM and as a homebrew designer the following question:
How much damage is one point of attack bonus worth?
An example of this might be a choice between a weapon that gives +1/+1 vs one that adds 2 damage. The latter is better if +1 to attack is worth less than 1 damage.
I recognize that this is circumstantial and that there are multiple variables.
I ended up with the following equation (for hit + crit < 1):
(extra damage) = (accuracy bonus)(total average damage on hit)/[20(hit chance + crit chance)]
Running some numbers, this looks reasonable:

High damage attacks want accuracy more than lower damage attacks, as a higher extra damage term is needed to compensate for the lower chance of hitting. A greatsword with max modifier (assuming a 65% hit and 5% crit chance) results in 1 accuracy being worth 0.86 damage. By comparison, a level 20 rogue's sneak attack with a shortsword (11d6 + 5) at the same base accuracy results in 1 accuracy being worth 3.1 damage.
Against highly-armored targets, accuracy is worth more (holding damage constant). Because a miss is worth 0 damage. If you only hit on a 20 (hit + crit = 0.05), 1 accuracy is worth 12 damage for that same greatsword scenario. By comparison, if you hit on a 3 (combined hit + crit = 0.9), 1 point of accuracy is only worth 0.67 damage. And of course if you hit on a 19+...accuracy isn't very much value at all.

On average, using this formula and choosing a (hopefully) unbiased set of data points, I get that 1 point of accuracy is roughly worth 2-ish points of damage (1.8 - 2.5, depending on exactly what I choose). This matches the 2014 D&D's -5/+10 features.
So the question--is my math right? Are there considerations that need to be included to have a more accurate representation of the tradeoff?

I’ve closed this as a duplicate, I think the analyses in the linked question address what you’re asking here.
